# CMake: Add an external project but exclude from target "all"

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to add an [external project](http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html) in CMake but to exclude it from the `all` build target?

I've looked at the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` option which is used with `ADD_EXECUTABLE` but I don't think this works with an external project.

Alternatively I'd be happy if I could change the default target for CMake, but I I think that's hard-coded to `all`.

For the project that I'm working on I am generating Unix Makefiles with CMake and right now I'm using CMake version 2.8.10.2.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Even if the option `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` is not used upon adding the target by the `ExternalProject_add` command, the option can be activated retroactively by setting the [`EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL.html) property of the external project target, i.e.:

```
ExternalProject_add(MyExternal
  URL ... )
set_target_properties(MyExternal PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't have time to try it till today, but that's just the setting I needed.